# Way to identify Salesforce edition using API?

Tags: api

Is there an API method to return what edition current customer is using?

Comment: can you expand on why you want to determine this? typically there are better ways to control things than the edition in use.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can query the OrganizationType from the [Organization](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_organization.htm) object.

```
select OrganizationType from Organization
```

As of API 32 possible values are:
["Team Edition","Professional Edition","Enterprise Edition","Developer Edition","Personal Edition","Unlimited Edition","Contact Manager Edition","Base Edition"]

Where Team Edition is commonly referred to as Group Edition and Base Edition is known as Performance Edition.

These values are derived from:

`Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr = Schema.sObjectType.Organization.fields.OrganizationType;
List<String> values = new List<String>();
for(Schema.PicklistEntry ple : dfr.getPicklistValues()){
    values.add(ple.getValue());
}
system.debug(JSON.serialize(values));`

Comment: Note that this requires the "View All Data" perm to run, or must be run in apex declared as without sharing!

Comment: @Daniel, could you add in what the possible options for OrganizationType are?

Comment: I can confirm (from [SOQLXplorer](http://www.pocketsoap.com/osx/soqlx/)) that another is "Developer Edition".

Comment: If you're using [databasedotcom gem](https://github.com/heroku/databasedotcom), then you can do something like this: `client.materialize('Organization').first.OrganizationType`

Comment: Note that when in a Group Edition org, the actual returned value is "Team Edition", not "Group Edition". I have edited the post to reflect this. The [API docs for the `Organization` object](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_organization.htm) do not list out all possible values, so I'm curious, Daniel, where you got your list of possible values.

Comment: @zachelrath, I didn't add Group Edition to the list. That was a suggested edit from another user.

Answer (score 3):

Use below class to determine the instance and edition of salesforce.

```
public class whereAmI{

// First method will give us the edition as a string 

public Static String getEdition(){

    // Organization object FTW!
    Organization[] org = new Organization[]{};
    org = [select Id, OrganizationType from Organization limit 1];

    // Check to make sure we have a result
    if(org.size()==1)
        return org[0].OrganizationType;
    else
        return '[still lost...]';
}


// Next method tells us if we're in a sandbox

public Static Boolean isSandbox(){

    String host = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost();
    String server = host.substring(0,host.indexOf('.'));

    // It's easiest to check for 'my domain' sandboxes first 
    // even though that will be rare
    if(server.contains('--'))
        return true;

    // tapp0 is a unique "non-cs" server so we check it now
    if(server == 'tapp0')
        return true;

    // If server is 'cs' followed by a number it's a sandbox
    if(server.length()>2){
        if(server.substring(0,2)=='cs'){
            try{
                Integer.valueOf(server.substring(2,server.length()));
            }
            catch(exception e){
                //started with cs, but not followed by a number
                return false;
            }

            //cs followed by a number, that's a hit
            return true;
        }
    }

    // If we made it here it's a production box
    return false;
  }
}
```

Courtesy : http://www.michaelforce.org/recipeView?id=a0Ga000000Ekp65EAB

Comment: so not all sandboxes start with cs?