# In Managed App, how does one determine Customers Org size?

Tags: licenses, userlicense, org

In one of our AppExchange app, we want to determine customer org size. To do so, what's the best way to find out the same?

Maybe I make a query on UserLicense Object which will give information about the total number of User Licenses & how many of them are currently being used. Specially count below license types only?

- Salesforce
- Salesforce Platform
- Salesforce Platform One
- Salesforce Platform Light
- Lightning Platform - One App
- Lightning Platform App Subscription

Comment: Chirag, the answer to this really depends on what you mean by "customer org size" -- what is it that you really want to know? If you query UserLicense and find out that they have 500 Salesforce licenses... what does that tell you? What are you going to do with that information?

Comment: my bad, I should have added a brief of use-case. We trying to gauge whether its an SMB or Enterprise customer based on their UserLicense count and accordingly offer our appexchange app tiered pricing. This is still being evaluated.

Comment: Got it. Besides the license counts, you can also look at the OrganizationType (mentioned in [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/216/way-to-identify-salesforce-edition-using-api))

Comment: @ChrisJohnson got it, so license count is the best way to judge an org size? Also shall I count only above license types or add/remove other license types as well?

Comment: I guess I don't know enough about your specific situation to answer that. License count is certainly one way could judge org size. But one could also consider number of logins, number of records, etc.

Comment: Okies. Thanks for your input.